# Unable to install Windows Store apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

I'm unable to install any apps from the Windows Store. When installing apps I am just presented with the following error:
Code: 0x80070005

[image]

I so far have tried all the fixes listed in the link below to no avail:

https://www.windowscentral.com/fix-pending-apps-windows-10-store

I am using Windows 10 Pro and my current build of Windows is as follows:

[image]

Is there anything else I can do to resolve this issue?

In regards to Ramhound's questions below:

- Have you used any applications to improve your privacy? No
- Have you used any applications to disable the "spying" features within Windows 10? No
- Have you change the default permissions of the WindowsApps directory? No
- Is this computer connected to an AD domain? No

Comment: Edit your question, do not submit a comment, and supply the following information.  Your Windows 10 build, you can determine this information, by using `winver`.  We also need to know the edition of Windows 10 you are using.  Have you used any applications to improve your privacy?  Have you used any applications to disable the "spying" features within Windows 10?  Have you change the default permissions of the WindowsApps directory?  Is this computer connected to an AD domain?

Answer (score -1):

The current build is Windows 10 1709 (OS build 16299.201). I suggest you check and install all available Windows Updates to make your computer to the latest build.

Alternatively, you can upgrade to Windows 10 1709 via Media Creation Tool provided by Microsoft:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

Afterwards, try downloading the app from Windows Store again.

Comment: This ended up being a short term fix to the problem as the issue has returned.